# CKEditor on Drupal7: Select "Enter mode is disabled

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor

I have CKEditor on Drupal 7. I want to change what happens if I press Enter. So I found in settings the particular field. But the select is disabled.
Don't anybody know, how to change it, please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution, so I edited the output directly in the code.